# How to change position and dimension of a button in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

We are creating buttons calling following function in a loop.
The problem is dimension and coordinates we are giving are not being used.
Android apparently using some other logic when placing them.

```
fun createAButton(
                  name: ArrayList<Button>,
                  x: Float,
                  y: Float,
                  w: Int,
                  h: Int){

     name.add(Button(this))
     var index = name.size - 1

     myActionMenuView.addView(name[index])

     name[index].width = w
     name[index].height = h
     name[index].x = x
     name[index].y = y

  }
```

Comment: What is going on, can't we put a button wherever we want on a layout giving coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work for you

```
fun createAButton(
              name: ArrayList<Button>,
              x: Float,
              y: Float,
              w: Int,
              h: Int){

 name.add(Button(this))
 var index = name.size - 1

 myActionMenuView.addView(name[index])

 name[index].width = w
 name[index].height = h
 name[index].x = x
 name[index].y = y
 name[index].layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w,h) 
}
```

set height and width using LayoutParams

Comment: When I use last line you suggested app does not run and I see app keeps stopping window.

Comment: A did something as following. Before value.width and value.Height was -1 after 50 but appearance of the buttons did not change.  **var value = name[index].getLayoutParams()
        value.width = 50
        value.height = 50
        name[index].setLayoutParams(value)**

Comment: I wonder where I supposed to use button.x, button.y, button.width, button.height. Because I used the same structure for TextView and it is worked.